# Regex to exclude certain strings from path

Tags: regex

I need a regex that will accept all paths except those that have `/cantbe` or `/cantbe/this`

So

```
this/is/ok/filename.tr
```

is a match but

```
this/is/ok/cantbe/filename.tr
```

or

```
this/is/ok/cantbe/this/filename.tr
```

are not matches.

I tried

```
.*(?!\/cant\/)(?!\/cant\/this).*\.tr
```

but the paths above are still matches

Comment: Would `is/this/ok/cantbesomething` be a match? And since I assume `/it/cantbe/that` shouldn't be a match, since it contains `/cantbe`, why do you have the extra rule that `/cantbe/this` cannot be in it, since that already contains `/cantbe`?

Comment: @Grismar `is/this/ok/cantbesomething` would not be a match. You are right that I can drop `/cantbe/this` since it is included in `/cantbe/`. Basically any path with `/cantbe/` is not a match.

Comment: The `.*` should be inside the lookahead, and use an anchor `^` to assert the start of the string `^(?!.*\/cantbe).+` See https://regex101.com/r/9nGZfx/1

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
^((?!\/cantbe\b).)*$
```

Try it out [here](https://regex101.com/r/wjmUzB/1)

This is explained quite well on this question
[Regular expression to match a line that doesn't contain a word](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/406230/regular-expression-to-match-a-line-that-doesnt-contain-a-word)